# C++ arrow operator with pre-increment: With or without parentheses is the same?

Tags: c++

Question from the course:

> Watch the parentheses around the argument of the ++ operator. Are they
>   really needed? What will happen when you remove them?

Initially there was only one `cout` expression. I added another one to see the difference, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Class {
public:

    Class(void) {
        cout << "Object constructed!" << endl;
    }

    ~Class(void) {
        cout << "Object destructed!" << endl;
    }
    int value;
};

int main(void) {
    Class *ptr;

    ptr = new Class;
    ptr -> value = 0;
    cout << ++(ptr -> value) << endl;
    cout << ++(ptr -> value) << endl;
    delete ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

My idea was to test it again without parentheses and see what is different:

```
    ...
    cout << ++ptr -> value << endl;
    cout << ++ptr -> value << endl;
    ...
```

The result is the same in both cases. Thus I conclude: No difference.

Can someone explain and correct please? Why would they ask that question if there is no difference? My feeling is there is a subtlety I am missing.

Result:

```
Object constructed!
1
2
Object destructed!
```

Comment: First of all, you REALLY shouldn't be putting spaces before and after the arrow when you access an instance...

Comment: They are probably testing your knowledge of operator precedence, the idea is whether the ptr will be incremented or the value member will be, see the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), here `->` has higher precedence than prefix `++` so the parentheses don't make a difference

Comment: In c++ there is no need to write (void), because () means no arguments, instead of Cs interpretation. Just don't write them. That's 'ugly'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference because `->` has a higher precedence than `++`. This means that `++ptr -> value` is always parsed as `++(ptr->value)`.

Regardless of how the compiler will see your code, you shouldn't write it like that, because someone who doesn't know C++ operator precedence rules might think the code does something different from what it actually does. `++(ptr->value)` is far clearer.

Comment: Yes for keeping the parenthesis for clarity. Alternatively `++(*ptr).value` also works.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question is **[Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)**

As you can see, the `->` operator has a higher precendece than the `++` (prefix) and `<<` operator

However, you always should write code, that is clear to the programmer. The compiler always knows the rules, but a human does not and an etra pair of parenthesis does not matter to the resulting code.

But beware, there is a difference if you use postfix-`++`. They have a higher precende, than the `->` operator and in that case you must use parenthesis. So, to be sure, always use them ;)

Comment: suffix increment and arrow operators both have the same precedence.

Comment: @4klvlh no, they don't. *"Operators are listed top to bottom, in descending precedence"*

Comment: if what you understand from the table was the case, then `<` and `>` would have different precedence levels. See the leftmost column of the table. Operators with the same precedence "number" have the same precedence levels.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the Element selection through pointer(arrow ) has higher precedence than prefix increment and decrement operator. For more information see

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence